# Search suggestion with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to replicate the suggestion seen on: https://devart.withgoogle.com/ when you start typing certain words in the search box.

For my HTML I have:

```
<form ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <input name="q" ng-model="query" ng-keypress="querySuggest()" type="text">
    <div class="search__enhance">
        <span class="search__offset" ng-bind="suggestion.query"></span>
        <span class="search__suggestion" ng-bind="suggestion.text"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then in my controller I have:

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location) {

    $scope.querySuggest = function () {

        var haystack = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Small Talk", "Scheme"];

        $scope.suggestion.query = '';

        $scope.suggestion.text = '';

    }

});
```

So the next bit is to show the results inside the input (splitting what the user has typed and what the suggestion is).

[image]

What I'm confused with is how to do the following:

1. Show the search suggestion (minus the entered query in the search__suggestion span element.
2. Show the query in the search__offset span element **(from what I can tell they don't show the value in the input itself...**)
3. Match the entered query with the haystack array.

Any ideas for these three?

Comment: Could you please tell me the css for search__enhance class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a separate element "behind" the actual input. Use that element to show suggestiong which you'll fetch using the onchange listener on the input element. That takes care of #1 and #2.

For #3, you can do a simple matching against the haystack.

---

Here's a fully working example, use the right arrow to confirm the suggestion:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('SearchCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $location) {

    $scope.suggestion = {};

    var haystack = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Small Talk", "Scheme"];

    $scope.querySuggest = function($event) {
      if ($event.keyCode == 39) {    // confirm suggestion with right arrow
        $scope.query = $scope.suggestion.text;
        return;
      }
      $scope.suggestion.text = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.query && haystack[i].indexOf($scope.query) === 0) {
          $scope.suggestion.text = haystack[i];
          console.log(haystack[i]);
          break;
        }
      }

    }

  });
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}
.search__suggestion {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/normal Arial;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 3px;
  color: #aaa;
  z-index: -1;
}
input {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/normal Arial;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchCtrl" autocomplete="off">
  <input name="q" ng-model="query" ng-keyup="querySuggest($event)" type="text">
  <div class="search__enhance">
    <span class="search__suggestion" ng-bind="suggestion.text"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the css for search__enhance class.